# Inserting in UIViewtable after asynchronous task

Tags: swift, uitableview, asynchronous, swift3

I'm trying to update my tableView after an asynchronous task where I parse JSON data from a URL, I am learning Swift and I don't understand what is wrong with this code. Messages is an array of string, I am appending a message_body in it for each json object. I am waiting for the task to execute the HTTP request to call the method finishedLoading where I try to insert the rows in my tableView. I am getting this error `'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.'`

Thanks for helping

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
     cell.textLabel?.text = messages[indexPath.row]
     return cell
 }

func finishedLoading(array: Array<String>) {
    TableView.beginUpdates()
    TableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: messages.count-1, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
    TableView.endUpdates()
    TableView.reloadData()
}

public func init_chat()
{
        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "URL")!)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        let session = URLSession.shared

        session.dataTask(with: request) {data, response, err in
            let json = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? [String: Any]
            let data = json?["data"] as? [[String: Any]]
            for message in data! {
                if let name = message["message_body"] as? String {
                    self.messages.append(name)
               }
           }
        self.finishedLoading(array: self.messages)
     }.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this function:

```
func numberOfRows(inSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return messages.count
}
```

And replace this code:

```
self.finishedLoading(array: self.messages)
```

With this code:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Yes, this worked, but I still have to give credit to rmaddy, I use his advice too, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have several issues.

1. You are not reloading the table view on the main queue.
2. You are updating your data model (`messages`) on a background queue.
3. You are appending the new data to your main `messages` array but then you treat the insert like you have added only a single row.
4. You call `insertRows` and `reloadData`. Only call one of them.
5. You do need to use `beginUpdates/endUpdates` with a single call to `insert/delete/reloadRowsAt`.
6. You have lots of forced unwrapping.

To solve issue 1, wrap the call to `finishedLoading` inside `DispatchQueue.main.async`:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.finishedLoading(array: self.messages)
}
```

Solving issues 2 and 3 is more involved. Start by creating a local array to collect the new data. Then pass that array to `finishedLoading`. Then update `finishedLoading` to append that new array to `messages` and properly inform the table view of all of those new rows.

Here is updated code fixing all of the issues.

```
func finishedLoading(array: [String]) {
    let currentCount = messages.count
    messages.append(contentsOf: array)
    var newPaths = [IndexPath]()
    for row in 0..<array.count {
        newPaths.append(IndexPath(row: row+currentCount, section: 0))
    }
    TableView.insertRows(at: newPaths, with: .automatic)
}

public func init_chat()
{
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "URL")!)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    let session = URLSession.shared

    session.dataTask(with: request) {data, response, err in
        if let data = data {
            let json = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any]
            if let data = json?["data"] as? [[String: Any]] {
                var newData = [String]()
                for message in data {
                    if let name = message["message_body"] as? String {
                        newData.append(name)
                    }
                }
                if !newData.isEmpty() {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.finishedLoading(array: newData)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

I leave it as an exercise to get rid of the use of `try!` and replace it with a proper `do/catch/try`.

Disclaimer: The above code has not been tested. There might be typos.